# Microsoft installer project does not update app.config files on install on Windows server 2016

Tags: server, installation, project, app-config, windows-server-2016

I have a project where I have a Microsoft Install Project that makes MSI files.

When I install this MSI on my local PC it overwrites my app.config file just fine.

But when I do the same on a Windows Server 2016 the existing app.config does not get overwritten, even if version in the install is newer than the existing one.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: It is a well-known issue that non-versioned files do not get overwritten if the create and modify dates of the file are different ([file-versioning rules](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO3568.html)). This means the file has been modified since it was created. Will dig up some further links, but can't right now. Please verify that this file has different create and modify dates. Just go to file properties.

Comment: But the funny part is that is works just fine on my local computer.

Comment: Yes, because the file was never modified on your system. Then the create and modify dates match and the file is seen as "unmodified" and hence over-writable.

Comment: I have updated the local installation many times and the app.config files was also updated when ever there was a change to it.